# Длина строки length()

Tags: c++

Почему при применении метода length() к строке в C++ каждый символ из кириллицы считается как два символа? Результат, словно length() считает байты.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    cout << name.length() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: функция `.length()` и должна считать байты

Comment: Случайно не в онлайн-компиляторах проверяешь?

Comment: Нет, g++ на Linux Mint.

Answer (score 1):

Кириллические символы в кодировке UTF-8 занимают как раз по 2 байта.
Для подсчета предлагают использовать функцию mbstowcs вот тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117393/utf-8-strings-length-in-linux-c

Answer (score 0):

С использованием [UTF8-CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/):

```
size_t LengthOfUtf8String(const std::string &utf8_string) {
    return utf8::unchecked::distance(utf8_string.begin(), utf8_string.end());
}

std::cout << LengthOfUtf8String(name) << std::endl();
```

Answer (score -1):

Кто сказал, что два символа? Это если UTF-16, то два, а если UTF-32, то четыре, а если UTF-8, то вообще переменное значение...

Простенький класс работы со строкой, использующий C++11/boost тут: https://github.com/sitev/cjCore/blob/master/src/object.cpp

Найди там класс String, достаточно просто для понимания...

Comment: Извините, но ваш код ужасен

Comment: на вкус и цвет... чем ужасен то код?

Comment: Код работает и под Windows и под Linux. В первом случае используется C++11, во втором - boost. Это сделано из-за для того, что GCC 4.9.2 не поддерживает полностью C++11.

Comment: Наверно потому, что вы пытаетесь превратить C++ в Java.
Вы хотя бы предупреждения читайте http://pastebin.com/gdV3cUcL

Comment: ок... спасибо, что посмотрели - предупреждения почищу в ближайщее время...